# Invalid MEX-file when compiling with openMP and gcc

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, openmp, mex

I am trying to compile a mex file using openMp on win7_64. The file compiles fine, but when I try to run it I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid MEX file, the specified module could not be found
```

DependecyWalker tells me, that LIBGOMP_64-1.DLL is missing which I guess is the openmp library.

I installed the latest version of TDM-GCC and selected to install openmp support in the installer.

Is there anything else I have to install?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you find `libgomp` dll? if so, does your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to its location?

Comment: Yes, libgomp_64-1.dll is in the installation directory of mingw and the path variable (win7) points to it...I just copied the dll in the directory where the mex file is and now it works... thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution. It could benefit future visitors if you could put that solution (copy libgomp_64-1.dll to the same directory as the mex file) in an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the LIBGOMP_64-1.DLL from the mingw/bin directory to the directory where the mex file is and now it works...